# JSON query String with special letters

Tags: java, json, http

I'm trying to send a HTTPPost to a web server using JSON arrays.

Is there a problem with this implementation?

```
sendData = "?type=1&registID=aaabbbccc&email=xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url + sendData);
```

There may be some special letters such as _, -, @, . on both the ID part and the email part.

I think this is causing the return of invalid results from the server.

How can I fix this?

//////
The returned results looks like this.

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 - Error report</title>.......
<body>HTTP Status 404 - ..........<u>The requested resource is not 
available.</u>....</body></html>
```

Comment: I don't think an underscore, hyphen, at symbol, or period character is enough to break the get query. With that values does it break? (i.e show us an example where you get an invalid result from your server)

Answer (score 2):

It Must Be A Invalid Character In Your sendData. encodeULI() Usually Used When We Want To Convert Unaccepted Charters To Valid Code Can Be Handled By Browser Through The URL. I'm Not Really Sure But This Function Should Solve The Problem.

Try this

```
sendData = "?type=1&registID=aaabbbccc&email=xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url + encodeURI(sendData));
```

Comment: I'm Not Really Sure About The Answer And I'm Really Week In English So I Prefer To Write Short

Answer (score 0):

As a result, the problem had nothing to do with this source.

It was an error caused by the server.

The server developer told me after two hours of trying to do something with this issue, that the server was actually not operational.

The answer by MSS caused a different error after the server was back on state.

Conclusion : special characters such as underscores, @, . will not cause any problems on communicating with the server.